# require / extend ClassMethod from a separate file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a module with some "class" or "DSL" methods which at the moment looks like:

```
module Things
  module ClassMethods
    def thing id, title, **options
      # ... create and register a thing ...
    end

    # ... more DSL methods ...
  end
  extend ClassMethods

  # define project things
  thing :ruby, "Ruby programming language"
  thing :rails, "Ruby on Rails web framework"
  thing :active_support, "ActiveSupport library"
end
```

So I define the DSL methods in the `ClassMethods`, extend the `Things` with `ClassMethods` then use the DSL in the module body. I've chosen the name `ClassMethods` following the convention I see though out rails, although the module is not an active record Concern.

Now I would like to separate the DSL definition from its usage, so I split the code into

`lib/things/class_methods.rb`:

```
module Things
  module ClassMethods
    def thing id, title, **options
      # ... create and register a thing ...
    end

    # ... more DSL methods ...
  end
end
```

and `lib/things.rb`:

```
require_relative "things/class_methods"

module Things
  extend ClassMethods

  # define project things
  thing :ruby, "Ruby programming language"
  thing :rails, "Ruby on Rails web framework"
  thing :active_support, "ActiveSupport library"
end
```

But after this something breaks: the code works as intended the first time after restarting the rails server, but subsequent requests that use this module raise obscure errors or complain that DSL methods aren't defined or otherwise behave as if the DSL calls didn't do what they were supposed to. It feels as if the `extend ClassMethods` line picks up a wrong module `ClassMethod`, but then I don't understand why i works initially.

Any idea what exactly goes wrong with my approach and what's the best solution to the problem? Should I rename the DSL module so it doesn't clash with `ClassMethods` defined elsewhere in the framework? Or is there anything else I can do to keep using the name `ClassMethods` without a conflict?

Comment: _"raise obscure errors or complain that DSL methods aren't defined"_ – could you show those error messages?

Comment: _"Any idea what exactly goes wrong"_ – could be related to [autoloading and reloading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html). Have you tried to use a Concern?

Comment: I haven't tried to use a Concern because this module is not intended to be included into classes, but simply used as a sort of singleton. But I might give it a go just to see if anything improves.

Comment: one error I can trigger reliably is **"undefined method `thing' for Things:Module"**

Comment: aha, another thing I notice: it works after restart of the rails server and seems to keep working as long as I don't touch the `lib/things.rb` or `lib/things/class_methods.rb`. As soon as I edit and save one of these I get **"undefined method `thing` ..."**

Comment: That's definitely sounds like a reloading problem. Maybe it helps to add `require_dependency 'things/class_methods'` to `lib/things.rb` or to use a fully qualified constant, i.e. `extend ::Things::ClassMethods`

Comment: The qualified constant, even simply `Things::ClassMethods` seems to have fixed all my problems, thanks! If you write it up as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails sometimes loses track of constants during [autoloading and reloading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) and needs some help.

This can either be an explicit dependency:

```
# lib/things.rb
require_dependency 'things/class_methods' # <- tells Rails that we depend on this
require_relative 'things/class_methods'

module Things
  extend ClassMethods

  # ...
end
```

Or by using a fully qualified contant:

```
# lib/things.rb
require_relative 'things/class_methods'

module Things
  extend ::Things::ClassMethods

  # ...
end
```

It might be enough to use `extend Things::ClassMethods`, provided that you don't have another `Things` module nested under `Things`.

Which approach works, seems to depend on your class structure and autoloading configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the `/lib` directory to your `application.rb` file using the `.autoload_paths` method?